# Insert rows into a table from another table row?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, insert, cursors, row

I've got a table **Schedule**

| Id | unserId | Sunday | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | Saturday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 10 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 20 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

I need to insert lines from ***one*** row in table **Schedule** into ***seven*** rows in table **Attending**, So the result would looks like this:

| Id | userId | Day | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 10 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 10 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 10 | 3 | 1 |
| 5 | 10 | 4 | 0 |
| 6 | 10 | 6 | 0 |
| 7 | 10 | 5 | 0 |
| 8 | 20 | 0 | 1 |
| 9 | 20 | 1 | 0 |
| 10 | 20 | 2 | 0 |

To solve this, I think of using **Cursor**:
I would use two cursors, one for each row in the table Schedule and the other for the 7 days of each row!

Is it the right way of doing it, or there is a better way of doing it?

Comment: Cursors are notorious for being performance bottlenecks and there's almost always a much more efficient solution with not using one. What you're likely looking for here is [`PIVOT` or really more so `UNPIVOT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16) if you're trying to go from the structure of `Schedule` to the structure of `Attending`.

Answer (score -1):

Unpivot data

```
SELECT userid, weekday, status 
  FROM  (SELECT userid, Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday,Thursday,Friday, Saturday
           FROM schedule) scd 
UNPIVOT
(Status FOR weekday IN (Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday,Thursday,Friday, Saturday)) AS unpivot;
```

Comment: This query clearly answer of the question. Test it. Why downvoting?